# How to examine a urllib2 object in Python?

Tags: python, urllib2

I am learning Python at the moment, and I come from a Java/C++ and C background. I usually like to "examine" the "objects" in debuggers to get a better understanding of what is going on, so excuse my question if it seems odd for python.

I was reading the `urllib2` documentation at Python's website. The following example was shown:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> for line in urllib2.urlopen('http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/timer.pl'):
...     if 'EST' in line or 'EDT' in line:  # look for Eastern Time
...         print line
```

I understand that `urlopen` will download the content of a page.

Does `urlopen` download the HTML content? I tried doing the following:

```
content = urllib2.urlopen('http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/timer.pl')
print content
```

which yields an object. What is the nature of this object? Is it a dictionary-like object? If so, how can I examine what its key-values are? Would that be done using `pickling` in Python?

I am aware of the `geturl()` method, but I'd like to understand fully what `urlopen()` does and return.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and you can print the content using:

```
print content.read()
```

also, I'd like to suggest IPython, so you can inspect object methods and attributes very easily:

```
dir(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

place this at any point in your source, like a breakpoint - it allows you to interactively inspect names and objects. once you're in, you can also use

```
import inspect
```

which has a number of options for inspecting the properties and methods of an object http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#module-inspect

also `dir(my_object)` is a cheap way to do something similar

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib2#urllib2.urlopen):

> This function returns a file-like object with two additional methods: ...

So you can read it like a file (as you already do).

Comment: File-like objects behave like [File Objects](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects).